# My Tab bar button image isn't showing up

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode-storyboard, xcode9

This is where the issue is, the Upload button image in the tab bar is not showing up.

[image]

On the Storyboard everything seems fine.

[image]

Every other tab bar button is able to work except the Upload button. I can't seem to figure out why. I did read the other posts on Stack Overflow and tried to figure out the issue and they don't seem to work. I am using Xcode 9. Thanks for everyone that helps me out. :)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your selected the image for tab bar item in your storyboard attributes inspector like below:

[image]

Comment: Yes I did that. But it isn't showing up at all either.